# RequiredFieldValidator with InitialValue that has newline characters not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I'm using an ASP.NET RequiredFieldValidator control, and I'm setting the InitialValue property to a string that contains two newlines ("\n\n").

When I perform validation and I have not changed the control's value from its initial value, the validator does not fire, when it should.

The reason I've found for this is that when I view the page source, the auto-generated javascript that sets the validator's initial value is escaping the initial value to "\\n\\n", which means that the initial value and the control's value are effectively different and passes validation when it shouldn't.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out for myself, but I'm not happy with the way the Validator control replaces \n with \\n.

When building my string that previously had embedded \n in it, instead, I used vbLf, which the Validator replaces with \n.  I then just had to make sure that when I set the value of the control being validated, I replaced any occurrence of vbLf with \n, so that the 2 strings matched for validation.